# Change from one Activity to another

Tags: java, android, eclipse, list

I am trying to implement a TO-DO List an when I click on an item on the list-view I need it to go to another activity.
This is my code:

```
TextView tvItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvItem);

tvItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent it = new Intent(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ItemView.class)) ;   
        startActivity(it);

    }
```

Please Help

Comment: Look for `Intent`. You will find dozens of similar questions with answers here or anywhere else....

Comment: If you have a specific problem you can't get further - happy to help. Currently, the question sounds like you haven't done any research to do it yourself and more like "guys, please do my jobs for me".

Comment: And what is the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To go to ne next activity add this to you onItemClickListner:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
this.startActivity (intent);
```

All saving of tha activity must be made on this overriden method

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);
  savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
  // etc.
}
```

The savedInstanceState bundle will be passed again to your activty in it's OnCreate method so you can retreive those values again a reassigned them to where they were.

If eveything is set up correctly, to go back to the previous activity you only need to call finish() on the current activity.

Hope it helped!

Comment: If this was the answer you were looking for please mark it as an answer using the checkmark on the left :)